# How to start writing performance tests on the project (JMeter + Selenium bundle)

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I want to start writing performance tests on my project (JMeter + Selenium bundle). The following questions arose:

1. Where to start? What questions should I set before I start writing tests?
2. On what metrics should I concentrate on the first chord, if I'm
   interested in stability and partial performance and, for example,
   the speed of page loading?
3. Is it possible to integrate with the existing Test Automation
   Framework to avoid writing tests specifically for JMeter from
   scratch?

I will be glad to any other advice, tips, links, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to determine your goal prior to starting any testing, for example you can ask around for any [SLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement) or [NFRs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) you can stick to. If they don't exist you can mimic real-life usage of your application and increase the load until errors start occurring or response time exceeds reasonable values (it is highly unlikely that use will wait for page to load for more than i.e. 20 seconds)
2. It depends on the nature of application under test, check out [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) for high level overview. The key points are:

   - response time
   - throughput (requests per second)
   - application under test health (how much headroom in terms of CPU, RAM, network/disk IO is left)
   - how do KPI's correlate (i.e. when you add more users does throughput increase, remain the same or decrease)
   - how (if) your application scales
   - etc.
3. For JMeter there is one main rule: JMeter test should represent real user using real browser as close as possible (mind cookies, headers, cache, embedded resources, think times, etc.). You can build a test "skeleton" fairly quickly and easily using [JMeter Proxy Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). For Selenium it will be enough to stick to main [OOP principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) plus [Page Objects](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp) pattern.